# Running multiple for loops in batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file, curl, encryption

Below is my requirement

- My vbs file will call a batch with 5 parameters where one of the parameter is path of xml file
- Inside the batch file, I want to run 3 FOR loops sequentially
- First FOR loop will check all xml file starts with text*.xml and post the content into internal website using curl command
- Second FOR loop will check all xml file starts with encrypted*xml and convert into encrypted format and store it as encrypted*.txt (same name of xml) using openssl
- Third FOR loop will post the encrypted file into internal website using curl command.

Below is my code where %1 is path of the file. Reason for using cd.. twice because my openssl.exe is stored in that path and it will work only when we run it from the location where it kept.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd %1

::********* First Loop. Posting Plain text

SET i=1

for %%f in (Plaintext*.xml) do (
call :PTCURL "%%f" "%~2" "%~3" %~4

GOTO PLAINTEXTDONE

:PTCURL
curl -X POST  --insecure --data-urlencode xmlInput@Plaintext%i%.xml %2 >>%3 2>&1

Echo Success %4 Plaintext%i%
set /A i+=1
)
::********* First Loop Ends

::********* Second Loop. Encryption

:PLAINTEXTDONE

cd..
cd..

SET j=1

SET Path=%1\Encrypted_*.xml

for /R %%f in (%Path%) do (
call :OPENSSL "%%f" 

GOTO PLAINTEXTDONE

:OPENSSL

openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -K %5 -iv %6 -in %%f | openssl enc -e -base64 > %%f.txt

Echo Success %4 Encrypted%j%
set /A j+=1
)

::********* Second Loop Ends

::********* Third Loop Ends

SET k=1

for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%f in ('dir Encrypted_*.xml /b') do call :ECCURL "%%f" "%~5" "%~6" %2
GOTO PLAINTEXTDONE

:ECCURL

curl -X POST \ --insecure -H "x-cbg-encrypted-content: true" -H "x-cbg-partner-id: %%f" -H "x-cbg-rsa-encrypted-aes-key: %5" -H "x-cbg-aes-iv: %6" --data-urlencode xmlInput@%%f %2

Echo Success %4 Plaintext%i%
set /A k+=1
Pause:

:DONE
```

Here what I need is
- How to run For Loop one after another
- In third loop I need to pass file name with path in --data-urlencode xmlInput@%%f. How can pass file name with path and specific word of the file?
- Need a review and correction of my above code as its failing at first stage itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I see is that you have functions inside of a for loop. You can't do that. They need to be outside of any loop. I always put them at the bottom of the script. Make sure you end your main block of code with exit /b or goto :eof so it doesn't fall through to the function calls with no parameters.

This should get you closer:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal

cd %1

set "scurl=curl -X POST  --insecure --data-urlencode xmlInput@"

for %%f in (Plaintext*.xml) do (
  '%scurl% %%~nxf %2 ^>^>%3 2^>&1'
  Echo Success %4 %%~nf
)

SET "sPath=%1\Encrypted_*.xml"

for /R %%f in (%sPath%) do (
    'openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -K %5 -iv %6 -in %%f ^| openssl enc -e -base64 > %%f.txt'
     Echo Success %4 %%~nf
)


for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%f in ('dir Encrypted_*.xml /b') do (
    'curl -X POST \ --insecure -H "x-cbg-encrypted-content: true" -H "x-cbg-partner-id: %%~nxf" -H "x-cbg-rsa-encrypted-aes-key: %5" -H "x-cbg-aes-iv: %6" --data-urlencode xmlInput@%%~nxf %2'
    Echo Success %4 %%~nf
)
pause
```

Comment: Can you please correct the code as I am new to batch scripting?

Comment: Thanks Matt.. I will try this once I get the solution of another problem since that is holding from attempting this.

Comment: I learned new things today from you. Thanks a lot Matt for all your help and meet my code target delivery date :)